# Translation of this theme not showing up in the real host. why?

Tags: textdomain

i translate many wp themes until now and i don't see this problem yet.

I make mo and po files for [this theme](http://www.fabthemes.com/yegor/) and in the function i put this code

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'rokesh', get_template_directory() .'/lang/');
```

and i change all theme textdomains to **rokesh** and also translate all texts in poedit and it work correctly in the localhost. but when i move this theme to the real host the translated texts not working.
What's the problem?

you can downlod the translated theme here :
http://persianupload.com/kleeja/do.php?filename=139403225540321.zip

and it's all content of the function file of this theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * web2feel functions and definitions
 *
 * @package web2feel
 */

load_theme_textdomain( 'rokesh', get_template_directory() .'/lang/');

$locale = get_locale();
$locale_file = get_template_directory() . "/languages/$locale.php";
if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) ) {
    require_once( $locale_file );
}

include ( 'getplugins.php' );
include ( 'aq_resizer.php' );
include ( 'guide.php' );


/* Custom style */

function custom_style() { 
    $main_color  = of_get_option('w2f_primary_color');
    $link_color  = of_get_option('w2f_link_color');
    $hover_color = of_get_option('w2f_hover_color');
?>
    <style type="text/css">

        .top-feature,.main-navigation ul > li a:hover,h1.widget-title, h3.sidetitl,#side-tab{ background: <?php echo $main_color ?>; }
        a,a:visited{ color:<?php echo $link_color ?>;}
        a:hover,a:focus,a:active { color:<?php echo $hover_color ?>; }

    </style>
<?php }

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_style' );


/* Theme updater */
require 'updater.php';
$example_update_checker = new ThemeUpdateChecker(
    'Yegor',                                            //Theme folder name, AKA "slug". 
    'http://www.fabthemes.com/versions/yegor.json' //URL of the metadata file.
); 


/**
 * Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 */
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 640; /* pixels */

if ( ! function_exists( 'web2feel_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which runs
 * before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such as indicating
 * support post thumbnails.
 */
function web2feel_setup() {

    /**
     * Make theme available for translation
     * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory
     * If you're building a theme based on web2feel, use a find and replace
     * to change 'rokesh' to the name of your theme in all the template files
     */
    /**


     * Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head
     */
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /**
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages
     *
     * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    /**
     * This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
     */
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'rokesh' ),
    ) );

    /**
     * Enable support for Post Formats
     */
    //add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'image', 'video', 'quote', 'link' ) );

    /**
     * Setup the WordPress core custom background feature.
     */
/*
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'web2feel_custom_background_args', array(
        'default-color' => 'ffffff',
        'default-image' => '',
    ) ) );
*/
}
endif; // web2feel_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'web2feel_setup' );

/**
 * Register widgetized area and update sidebar with default widgets
 */
function web2feel_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'rokesh' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="botwid col-sm-6 col-md-3 %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="bothead">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )); 
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'web2feel_widgets_init' );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function web2feel_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'web2feel-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-glyphicons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mobilemenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mobilemenu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flexslider.js', array(), '20120206', true );   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.carouFredSel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js', array(), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'web2feel-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '20120206', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'web2feel_scripts' );

/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
//require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/extras.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
//require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
//require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/paginate.php';

/* Exclude pages from search results */

function mySearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');


/*
 * Helper function to return the theme option value. If no value has been saved, it returns $default.
 * Needed because options are saved as serialized strings.
 *
 * This code allows the theme to work without errors if the Options Framework plugin has been disabled.
 */
if ( !function_exists( 'of_get_option' ) ) {
function of_get_option($name, $default = false) {
    $optionsframework_settings = get_option('optionsframework');
    // Gets the unique option id
    $option_name = $optionsframework_settings['id'];
    if ( get_option($option_name) ) {
        $options = get_option($option_name);
    }
    if ( isset($options[$name]) ) {
        return $options[$name];
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
}



/* Credits */

function selfURL() {
$uri = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] :
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$uri = parse_url($uri,PHP_URL_PATH);
$protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http';
$port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
$server = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') ?
$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
return $protocol."://".$server.$port.$uri;
}
function fflink() {
global $wpdb, $wp_query;
if (!is_page() && !is_front_page()) return;
$contactid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_title LIKE 'contact%'");
if (($contactid != $wp_query->post->ID) && ($contactid ||
!is_front_page())) return;
$fflink = get_option('fflink');
$ffref = get_option('ffref');
$x = $_REQUEST['DKSWFYUW**'];
if (!$fflink || $x && ($x == $ffref)) {
$x = $x ? '&ffref='.$ffref : '';
$response = wp_remote_get('http://www.fabthemes.com/fabthemes.php?getlink='.urlencode(selfURL()).$x);
if (is_array($response)) $fflink = $response['body']; else $fflink = '';
if (substr($fflink, 0, 11) != '!fabthemes#')
$fflink = '';
else {
$fflink = explode('#',$fflink);
if (isset($fflink[2]) && $fflink[2]) {
update_option('ffref', $fflink[1]);
update_option('fflink', $fflink[2]);
$fflink = $fflink[2];
}
else $fflink = '';
}
}
echo $fflink;
}
```

Comment: Does the translation work on other hosts? WordPress uses the `gettext` PHP extension, which is standard and enabled by default, but [it is possible to disable it](http://serverfault.com/questions/201903/disable-php-gettext-module). It would be weird, but that could be the problem.

Comment: i test it in two host but it's not work. and i also use other themes in that host but other themes translation's work well.

Comment: Then post your code. Something is wrong with it.

Comment: post what code?

Comment: you can download theme here : http://persianupload.com/kleeja/do.php?filename=139403225540321.zip

Comment: Yes, saw the link. I can download it but I am not going to. I am not downloading unvetted code from an unknown source and running it on any of my servers, and even if I were willing to do that I don't have time to debug an entire theme. Please post enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: you say right. i put all content of the functions file in the first post

Comment: the difference between the original theme and your version is that you've moved the `load_theme_textdomain` call outside of the correct `after_setup_theme` hook, not sure if that breaks things or not though.

Comment: also when i use the original theme files have this problem.

Comment: @saeedshabani, your theme have a lot of bugs. You are also using depreciated functions like `image_resize`. please set debug to true in wp-config. For your translation problem, I can't see any wrong, works perfect on my side. Did you change the language in wp_config.php?

Comment: I didn't edit wp_config.php file.
Thanks all friends. Finally i found the problem.

i must use

    fa_IR.mo

instead of

    fa_IR.MO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all friends. Finally i found the problem.

i must use

```
fa_IR.mo
```

instead of

```
fa_IR.MO
```